# Cálculo em um DataGrid. C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Olá.
Há alguma maneira simples, trabalhando direto com o `db` de fazer cálculos na célula de um DataGrid.

Situação:
Eu tenho uma Coluna `Qtd`, outra `ValorUnitario` e outra `ValorTotal` de um determinado item. Gostaria que na Coluna `ValorTotal`, mostrasse o resultado da Qtd * ValorUnitario.

Isso em tempo de execução, de modo que se eu altero a quantidade ou o valor unitário de um produto, o resultado é modificado também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vai no Evento do DataGridView EndEdit e faz o calculo, ou seja, ao terminar a edicao de uma celula realiza alguma função. Mais o menos assim:

```
 private void dgvTabela_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int qt = Convert.ToInt32(dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["qtde"].Value);
            double valor= Convert.ToDouble(dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["valor"].Value);

            dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["total"].Value = qt * valor;

        }
```